# Label постоянно стремится сузится при присвоении нового текста

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, vcl

Это исходник Label2, формирующийся на `FormCreate`:

```
  Label2.Font.Height:=24;
  Label2.Font.Name:='Trebuchet MS';
  Label2.WordWrap:=True;
  Label2.Height:=64;
  Label2.Font.Color:=$ff0000;
  Label2.Width:=1000;
```

Далее идёт кнопка с событием `Button2Click`, и ни чего сложного в ней, для `Label2` не происходит, тем более не меняется его ширина. (ширина вообще ни где не меняется от заданной.)

Код на label2 в Button2

```
r:=Random(r);
Label2.Caption:=AdoQuery1.Fields[1].asString+' ['+IntToStr(r)+']';
```

И если тыкать кнопку много раз, то я заметил, что ширина `Label2` стремится потихоньку сужается по ширине, я так думаю, идёт к дефолтному значению.
В `Label2` попадают вопросы 2-4-х строчные, поэтому он постепенно превращается в столбик(!) в 6-10 и более строк.

Почему так происходит?

Comment: AutoSize = true?

Comment: @Sergey действительно true. Как-то я уже подзабыл забыл Delphi... 10 лет назад последний раз, что-то в нём серьёзное программировал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже, что стоит свойство `AutoSize = true`.

Старайтесь не использовать одновременно `AutoSize` и `WordWrap`, т.к. у них взаимно-противоречащее поведение (выровнять ширину по содержимому *vs.* выровнять содержимое по ширине)

Вероятно (можно проверить по исходникам VCL), что-то происходит раньше, а что-то позже, и получается, что вставили 123456, оно разбилось на 123-456, подогналась ширина, потом вставили 234567, оно разбилось по строкам согласно ширине как 23-45-67, а новая ширина опять уменьшилась чтобы соответствовать новому содержимому, и т.д.